# Python: count lines that occur together

Tags: python, linux, unix, io, python-2.6

I've been working on a script that will take in a css file as a txt file. The end result would be that the script would count the number of properties that occur more than once, which i have achieved, and to count the occurences of properties which appear as part of a group, e.g.

```
2 font-size:10px; + font-family:Helvetica;
3 width:100%; + height:inherit; + width:auto;
...etc
```

at the minute, my bash script will remove all block comments, leading and trailing whitespace, braces and css rule names from the txt file, leaving each property:value pair on its own line, and these are then counted and output to another file. I've now settled on using Python 2.6 for the next part of this task. How would I go about finding recurring groups of properties within the file? i.e. if font size and font family appear together in one rule, how could i check how many times this pair occurs throughout the file?

EDIT: just to clarify, I've decided to keep rule names and braces in the "stripped" file, and after removing whitespace, blank lines and comments the file will be in the following format:

```
.example-class{
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:Helvetica;
}
#example-element{
    height: auto;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:Helvetica;
}
...etc
```

With the preferred output for the above being:

```
2 font-size:10px; + font-family:Helvetica;
```

Comment: So what would be the expected output for the sample you have shown? `2 font-size:10px`? If the property name is the same but the value is different, should they still be grouped?

Comment: The preferred output would be the first code block in my question, e.g. <count> : <prop1>:<val1>; + <prop2><val2> etc. Question edited to show preferred output

Comment: I would probably not use bash for this. Maybe python instead. You will need to keep collections of existing groups and search and update them as you process the file.

Comment: would Bash or Awk be completely out of the question for this? Its just that the script is intended for myself and colleagues and we don't have admin rights on our Red Hat VMs, so a bash script would be preferable over having to go through hoops to install Python etc

Comment: python should be already there. modern linux distros have it already included as it used widely inside. e.g. yum from red hat is written in python. just check with "which python"

Comment: Yes I've discovered that each VM has access to Python 2.6, so im currently investigating a solution in that instead of Bash. Again, though, Im still not sure how to approach this problem